# Which size class is iPhone 5s, and which size class is iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, ios8, size-classes

I have a situation where I'd like a particular view to be 55 pixels high when it's iPhone 5s, and 65 pixels high when it's iPhone 6.

Can size classes help me achieve this? If so, what class should I use?
Right now it seems like

"Compact Width | Regular Height" is for all iPhones in portrait but I really want to have a different class for 5s and 6. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: They're bot the same size class. But you can access the pixel dimensions of the screen to treat them differently.

Comment: Thanks - how do you access pixel dimensions? :) You mean with just frame height and stuff like that?

Comment: You could work out a multiplier of the screen height that works for you, and set a constraint so that your view is always `x * height-of-container`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope... You cant distinguish between 5s and 6 with size classes.